# Beanstalkd bind address being ignored

Tags: beanstalkd

I am having trouble getting Beanstalkd to bind to right address. I am running Debian 8. Installed beanstalkd using apt. If I run `service beanstalkd start` the bind goes wrong. I am unable to connect using private network address. I also have this private IP in

> /etc/default/beanstalkd

Running `service beanstalkd status` will print:

> ● beanstalkd.service - Simple, fast work queue    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/beanstalkd.service; enabled)    Active: active
>   (running) since Mon 2015-08-10 08:29:37 EDT; 3s ago
>        Docs: man:beanstalkd(1)  Main PID: 1225 (beanstalkd)    CGroup: /system.slice/beanstalkd.service
>              └─1225 /usr/bin/beanstalkd -l [MY_PRIVATE_IP] -p 11300
>
> Aug 10 08:29:37 Messagewall3Beans beanstalkd[1225]:
>   /usr/bin/beanstalkd: inherited listen fd; ignoring option: -l
>   [MY_PRIVATE_IP] Aug 10 08:29:37 Messagewall3Beans beanstalkd[1225]: /usr/bin/beanstalkd: inherited listen fd; ignoring option: -p 11300

If I run beanstalkd manually using:

```
beanstalkd -V
```

Everything works just fine. I can connect using private IP. What's wrong with starting as a service? Why are those options being ignored?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the initial startup used a file file socket for local access and after you changed the bind address the restart process did not get rid of the socket, so it kept getting reused.

I had the same problem on a VM and a reboot fixed it for me.

Comment: I have been looking around for hours. I can't believe all I need to do was reboot...

Comment: wasted so much, reboot fixed it :)